# How can you get the TypeId of the inner value of a Rc or Boxed value, not the TypeId of the enclosing type?

Tags: rust

I'm using an associative list to associate `TypeId`s of event-types and `TypeId`s of who wants to receive them.

When I attempt to get the `TypeId` of an `Rc<Any>`, it gives you the same `TypeId` (the one of the `Rc` storing an `Any`) no matter what the `Any` is.

```
#![feature(get_type_id)]

use std::any::*;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let temp: Rc<Any> = Rc::new(13);
    let temp2: &Any = &5;

    assert_eq!(temp.get_type_id(), temp2.get_type_id()); //fails!
}
```

How can I get the `TypeId` of the associated `Any` on the inside?

I believe that `Rc<_>` implements the `Deref` trait as well as the `Any` trait. This means that you can dereference the `Rc` and call functions in the internal reference. It also means that the `Rc` has it's own associated `TypeId`. I'm not looking for the `TypeId` of the `Rc`, I'm looking for the `TypeId` from the dereferenced `Any`.

Comment: Why do you believe that you *can*?

Comment: Well, my assumption was that if an Any stored a value it also stored that values TypeId. Does it not? My assumption was I could store an Any and retrieve the TypeId of the internal Any's stored value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicitly dereference the wrapping type:

```
(*temp).get_type_id()
```

Comment: Man I should've tried that. Believe it or not, I thought the dereference operator was only valid on pointers. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @DavidBittner it's valid on anything that implements `Deref`. See [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-02-deref.html) for more.

Comment: Yeah, should've figured. I tend to blank on traits allowing operator overloading.